# Is it possible to prevent maximized windows from restoring down by moving the window?

Tags: windows-7

I would like to completely disable the possibility of mouse-dragging maximized windows. Ideally, the maximized window should restore down only by double-clicking, or pressing the 'maximize' button again. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this Microsoft Answers answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-can-i-disable-restore-down-when-i-drag-a/80c3a6c6-4d29-46f3-9fe8-4caee24ec6e9):

> 1. Click start, open control panel.
> 2. Open ease of access center.
> 3. Click on “make the mouse easier to use”.
> 4. Check “Prevent Windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen” has a check mark.
> 5. If not then please check it , click on apply and ok.

By the way, if you just want to move the windows between screens, drop it while the mouse cursor is on the upper edge of the second monitor and it will be automatically maximized again.

Or just press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>.

Comment: Amazing!!! I'm extremely surprised the option is already in the control panel. I was looking for registry hacks! Thank you so much!!